# Creating AMP page in Gatsby using gatsby-plugin-google-amp but pulling in all site styles

Tags: gatsby, amp-html, gatsby-plugin

I appreciate the plugin is no longer maintained in it's current form (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-amp/?=Amp) but wanted to use this as base for adding AMP pages to my site. I've installed the plugin fine and am able to create AMP versions of my required pages.

However whenever I try and import a CSS file or module I end up with all styles for my whole site being automatically prepended to the page (and hence invalidating the AMP page). How can I only import a single stylesheet? I've tried with CSS modules and no joy:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import ampStyles from "../assets/css/amp.module.css"
```

With no css import the pages validate fine. I only want to import a single stylesheet which will contain our limited AMP styles. Whats the best approach? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've not built an AMP app before, so I'm not 100% positive this will apply to you but you should be able to import the stylesheet at the top level of your app and all components under it should inherit the styles.

Another alternative may be to use `styled-components` library (which works in Gatsby) and so you'd only include the styles necessary for your components inline with your JSX/TSX.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but the inheritance is exactly what I don't want - I want the site to use inherited styles for all templates except the AMP template which I only want to include the AMP stylesheet. I basically want to do this due to CSS weight rather than elements inheriting styles incorrectly. For that reason I don't think CSS modules help either.

Comment: hmmm, I apologize, but my lack of experience in AMP is probably hindering my helpfulness, BUT let me ask some clarifying questions:  1) you want to have the inherited model for site, with the exception of your AMP templates? 2) is the problem that your AMP templates are inheriting CSS from other elements and it's causing issues with the AMP portion of your site?

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply. To answer your questions ... (1) Yes - Ideally we'd build this within the same site but the AMP template should only include the CSS for that template and not bundled CSS for the whole site. I think this used to work when Gatsby split CSS but now combines all CSS for the site. (2) The answer is the same - the problem is the AMP template will contain all CSS for the site,